# Swift - open specific tab from button click

Tags: ios, swift

I have implemented a `UITabBarController` and implemented a few tabs. Now I have a button in `UITabBarItem` from where I want to switch to a specific tab. I have seen answers using navigation controller but in my case, I am not using navigation controller.

> NOTE: I have copied this screenshot from the internet so please ignore the navigation bar. I want an answer without using navigation controller.

[image]

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just use this.

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = indexToWhichYouWantToMove;
```

`tabBarController` is the object for your `TabBarController`

Comment: how should I get the reference of my tab bar controller

Comment: You don't have to do it. Just like you use self.navigationController, you have to use it also. Just remember you embed your viewcontroller in tabbarcontroller @MoazKhan

Comment: Thanks for the answer and removing my confusion.

Comment: great! working fine thanks... but Tab icon name is not lighting

Answer (score 2):

The reference of your `tabBarController` in your `viewController`.

**Objective C:**

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
```

**Swift:**

```
tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
```

Comment: my tab bar controller only exists in storyboard. How should I get it's reference?

Comment: Just type tabBarController in viewController class it automatically suggest you for tab bar controller.. That's All. @MoazKhan

Comment: For objective C type self.tabBarController because you embed the view controller in tab bar controller @MoazKhan

Comment: You answer is correct and so was @aditya's but she answered first. Thanks anyways

Comment: No issue, Happy Coding :) @MoazKhan